# Triangular Area on hyperbolic surface

Tags: area, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I have read numerous paper over area calculation in hyperbolic geometry but just can't seem to understand how to calculate a triangle's area in hyperbolic geometry.  It would be nice to have a proof too.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: I did some more research since and I now understand how you can get the area using constant K and the defect of the triangle.  However now I am confused about how you are suppose to obtain constant K.  Do you NEED the area and the defect of at least one triangle to get the constant or is there any other way to calculate it?

Edit: Also, the formula on wikipedia contains a variable R, which I assume means radius.  So how can one find R or is it usually 1 like K?

Comment: Rather depends on how it's presented. In the upper halfplane model, the area is a double integral of $y^{-2}$ over the region. This can be used to prove the relation between the area and the sum of angles.

Comment: I was using the disk model.

Comment: @Steven The Klein disk model or the Poincare disk model?

Comment: The Poincare disk model.

Comment: It's just the angle defect.  The constant K is usually taken to be 1 (or -1, depending on what source you're reading).

Comment: But what unit would the answer be in? (centimeter, meter, etc)

Comment: @Steven: The unit will be the radian. The other units you mention do not exist in the hyperbolic space.

Comment: @studiosus Well, they could exist, in which case K would be the conversion factor.  If you want to use something like meters for length, then K is measured in radians per square meter.

Comment: @JimBelk: For the meter to exist you would have to transport a certain metal rod from Paris to the (a) hyperbolic space. This sounds like an interesting plot for a sci fi movie.

Comment: @studiosus Isn't a saddle an example of hyperbolic geometry?  I was basically hoping to use this formula to calculate the area of a triangle that's drawn on a saddle-like surface but I can't figure out how to go from radian to meters.  I assume I would need the radius but I have no idea how to get the radius of a saddle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit that most models of the hyperbolic plane have the build in assumption that the curvature of the surface = -1.

I did ask previously questions about this same question but never got a good answer,

But now i think there are some ways:

For example construct a equilateral triangle with sides length $m$ and angles $\alpha$ (radians)

Then the absolute length of a side (so with a curvature of -1 ) is:

$$ arcosh (\frac {\cos^2\alpha +\cos\alpha }{ \sin^2 \alpha } ) $$

so K is then $m$ divided by the calculated length .

Ps 1 : This just a rough idea, maybe I made some mistake somewhere.
and probably there are better ways. (or with smaller triangles, you need quite big triangles to get a measurable angle that is not $60^\circ $   )

Ps 2: I don't think area measures are a good starting point to calculate curvature.
Area is in hyperbolic geometry a tricky (multiply the area of a triangle by 4 and the shape of the triangle changes) , therefore in the above I stuck to length and angle measures. they are much less tricky

Comments invited , Maybe we can find together a better way :)